# Evaluate $\text{Ln}[(1+i)^7]$

Tags: complex-analysis

The solution i obtain is $\text{Ln}[(1+i)^7]=7\ln2^0.5 + i(7\pi/4)$. Wolfram Alpha gives me a completely different answer and was hoping someone could either confirm this answer or tell me where i went wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I have changed my answer to be Ln[(1+i)^7]=7ln(2)^0.5 - i(pi/4). Which i feel is a more appropriate answer

Comment: Yes. Don't forget that the logarithm is usually defined with the principal argument which takes values in $]-\pi,\pi].$

Comment: Hi,  -  please edit again to get the 0.5 exponent within {...} - I would do it but I am running into the idiotic 6 character minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. Using the properties of logarithms, the first term can also be written $3.5\ln 2$. More importantly, the capital L in Ln indicates "principal value" which for logarithms has the argument in $(-\pi, \pi]$ so it should be $-i(\pi/4)$.

What they show on Wolfram Alpha is exactly $3.5 \ln 2 - i(\pi/4)$, except that they use the numerical values of $\ln 2$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Switchin to exp form:

$$1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\frac\pi4}\implies(1+i)^7=(\sqrt2)^7e^{i\frac74\pi}=8\sqrt2e^{i\frac74\pi}.$$

The log is then:

$$\log[(1+i)^7]=\log(8\sqrt2)-i\frac\pi4,$$

Assuming you use the prinipal log. First term will be $\frac72\log2=3.5\log2$. To have $i\frac74\pi$ you'll need to take a log that is not the principal log, easiest choice being the one defined on all complex numbers save for positives, which is not standard AFAIK. Note that one of [Wolfram's alternate forms](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%5B%281%2Bi%29%5E7%5D&x=0&y=0) is exactly my result. You have (modulo fixing the exponent which is $^{0.5}$ and not $^0.5$, I take it $7\log2^{\frac12}$, which by properties of the real log is $\frac72\log2$. So fix the argument to $-\frac\pi4$ and Wolfram agrees with you :).